# Where is MATLAB Application Type Library?

Tags: c#, matlab, com

Where can I find "**MATLAB Application Type Library**" in Visual C# ?
I want to add the reference to my C# application.
The problem is I cannot find it in my COM Library.

I go **Project** > **Add Reference** > **COM Tab** > **???** (don't have MATLAB Library)

Where can I get that MATLAB library ?
Please help me...

Comment: You have installed matlab full version on your workstation already right?

Comment: I don't have MATLAB in my workstation.
Is there any other way ?
I want to interact C# and MATLAB functions or MATLAB file together...

Comment: @JinLing - The best way to get the file is to install MatLab on the computer.  The reason you cannot find it, is because, if its on the system its not registered.

Comment: @Ramhound - If the C# program is exported to the target computer which does not have MATLAB, can the target computer run the MATLAB functions ???

Comment: @JinLing - No.  The type library is just a definition of the interface to Matlab. It doesn't contain any Matlab code.  When using it, you are just making calls into an actual instance of Matlab (which must be installed on the computer you are running on).

Answer (score 4):

The Matlab type library (mlapp.tlb) is installed with matlab (in C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011b\bin\win32\ or similar).

This file describes the COM interface to Matlab you would also need Matlab installed on you PC to actually use Matlab from your C# program.

You can access Matlab files from C# without Matlab using the CSMatIO library

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319

This library wont read/write all Matlab file versions but it's still very useful.